# Devolver todos los martes 13 de un año

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, function, push

En la siguiente función, tengo que mostrar todos los martes 13 que tiene el año. Dicha función recibe como parámetro el año, y devolverá un `array` con los días encontrados. En caso de que el año no tenga ningún martes 13, pues devolverá 'false'.

Sobre lo que tengo hecho, ¿qué he de modificar o añadir para que me lo muestre correctamente?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function martes13(anio){
                var nuevoArray=[];
                for(var i=0;i<=11;i++){ /*meses*/
                    /*for(var j=1;j<=31;j++){*/ /*dias*/
                    var fecha=new Date(anio,i);
                    if(fecha.getDate()==13 && fecha.getDay()==2) {
                        nuevoArray.push(fecha);
                        document.write(fecha);
                    }
                }

                for(var j=0;j<nuevoArray.length;j++){
                    document.write(nuevoArray[i]);
                }

                if(nuevoArray=0) {
                   return false;
                }else{
                    return nuevoArray;
                }
            } 

            martes13(2019);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qué error te da?

Comment: Depurando el programa no aparece ninguno.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A la hora de buscar los martes 13, no tiene mucho sentido lo que haces, ya que creas una fecha por ejemplo 2019-01-01 y le preguntas si esa fecha es dia 13 y Martes. Tendría más sentido crear una fecha con el día 13 ya y preguntarle si esta fecha es Martes. Algo así:

```
var nuevoArray=[];
for(var i=0;i<=11;i++){ /*meses*/
            var fecha=new Date(anio,i,13);
            if(fecha.getDay()==2) {
                nuevoArray.push(fecha);
                document.write(fecha);
            }
    }
```

Y esta línea `if(nuevoArray=0) {` debería de ser:

```
if(nuevoArray.length==0) {
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Podrías poner `var nuevoArray=[]` delante del bucle para que sea más claro.

Comment: Listo, gracias @enxaneta .